# Wildcard for Firebase Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a database that works with IMDB ID's and has some categories beneath them.  I want to give any user, with or without authentication permission to create these categories, and modify some of the contents, but not others.  What kind of wildcard can I use to substitute for any IMDB ID

It looks roughly like this

```
"Movies"
|
|
|_______$IMDB_ID   //Should be read/writeable by anyone
               |
               |
               |
               __________Detail 1  //read/writeable by anyone
               |                 |
               |                 |___Detail Name  //read-writeable by anyone
               |                 |
               |                 |___Detail Score //readable by anyone, writeable with authentication
               |                 |
               |                 |____Detail Tally //readable by anyone, writeable with authentication
               |
               ____________Detail 2
                           |
                           |____Detail Name
                           |
                           |____Detail Score
                           |
                           |____Detail Tally
```

Comment: Answer below. If that's not what you're looking for, update your question to include a sample of the code of an operation that you want to succeed. And of an operation that you want to fail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking for this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Movies": {
      ".read": true,
      "$IMDB_ID": {
        "$DetailId": {
          "Detail_Name": { ".write": true },
          "Detail_Score": { ".write": "auth !== null" }
          "Detail_Tally": { ".write": "auth !== null" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```